# TypeError: Value does not implement interface EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

This works find in IE and Chrome, however, in Firefox, I get the error:

"TypeError: Value does not implement interface EventListener."

This code is posted by a php script, so I had to add the if statement determining if the id exists, first, to avoid errors in Chrome.

Here's the code:

HTML
   `<a id="Logout">Logout</a>`

JavaScript

```
if (document.getElementById("Logout") != null) {
    var Logout_Link = document.getElementById("Logout");
    Logout_Link.addEventListener('click', Logout, true);

    function Logout() {            
        var just_logged_out = 1;
        window.location.href = "logout-redirect.php";
    }
}
```

Comment: addEventListener('click', Logout, true)???why is this true

Comment: Well, in this case it doesn't actually matter. I just got into the habit because false was messing things up on some other code. I'll change it and see if it changes it, although I don't see why it will. Why are you against it? Does it use too much memory/processing power?

Comment: I changed it and I have the same problem. Clicking on 'Logout' does not do anything at all (only in Firefox).

Comment: Would be better if you first, get a element, and then check value is null or not in if statement. `var Logout_Link = document.getElementById("Logout"); if (Logout_Link) { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> if (…) {
>     function …() {            
>         …
>     }
> }
> ```

is invalid. Function declarations must be on the top level of function or program bodies, inside of blocks [their behaviour is implementation-dependent](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks). Move it outside the if-statement:

```
function Logout() {            
    var just_logged_out = 1;
    window.location.href = "logout-redirect.php";
}

if (document.getElementById("Logout") != null) {
    var Logout_Link = document.getElementById("Logout");
    Logout_Link.addEventListener('click', Logout, true);
}
```

So if the function was not declared [correctly], what's that odd error message? You might've expected something like `WRONG ARGUMENTS ERROR: handler is 'undefined'`. But actually it's not, [`Logout` does refer to your link element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here). And that does indeed not implement the `EventListener` interface (JavaScript functions do).

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thanks, and thanks for explaining. I'll make sure not to include a function in code that's dependent on a condition in the future.

Comment: Oh, you can; but you have to make sure it's a function expression which you (conditionally) assign to some variable. See [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/q/336859)

Comment: It's not invalid. It's just not strict. (With reason.)