# Firefox ReferenceError:... is not defined issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm using Datatables with server side processing, and i need to add some extra parameters to my query to do some filtering. This is how my setup looks like:

```
if($('#example').length) {
    var oTable = $('#listings').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": ajax_url+'?action=load_table_data',
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
             aoData.push( { "name": "filters", "value": get_table_filters() } );
        }
    });

    var tableFilterArray = {};
    //Setting up and changing the filters, etc...

    function get_table_filters() {
        return JSON.stringify(tableFilterArray);
    }
}
```

The script works fine in Chrome, but fails to run in Firefox, gives me the following error:

ReferenceError: get_table_filters is not defined

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HaXUR/3/

What am i missing here?

Comment: Did you try just moving the function up above oTable ?

Comment: @adeneo shouldn't function declarations like that be available anywhere within their parent function's scope? I think we're not getting all the code here.

Comment: @dhsto: Firefox has a special syntax for function declarations that appear in a statement block. It behaves more like a statement instead of a declaration, so it isn't hoisted. That's likely the issue here, but passatgt hasn't provided enough code to be certain.

Comment: i'll try to create a jsfiddle to show the issue, its a bit hard because of the ajax source

Comment: @passatgt: All relevant code belongs in the question. Please post it here.

Comment: @cookiemonster Interesting, I never knew that! I usually always have a function defined before I use it anyways, so I've never noticed this behaviour from firefox.

Comment: @dhsto: Yeah, it's sort of a weird situation. Technically it should be a SyntaxError to have a declaration in a block, but all browsers disobey that rule, and allow the declaration. Firefox takes it a step further and defines a special rule in their superset of ECMAScript for this. So none of them are strictly valid ECMAScript code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet

Comment: I found out the issue while creating the Jsfiddle(see updated question), but i'm hoping for an answer anyway, because i'm not sure what caused the issue:)

Comment: You already have the answer, you're declaring functions inside an if statement, and it's not really valid javascript, but most browsers will allow it, but in firefox there is no hoisting in statements, see the link to MDN

Comment: exact duplicate of [TypeError: Value does not implement interface EventListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845337/typeerror-value-does-not-implement-interface-eventlistener)

Answer (score 1):

Move the get_table_filters out of the if statement

```
if($('#example').length) {
var oTable = $('#listings').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": ajax_url+'?action=load_table_data',
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
         aoData.push( { "name": "filters", "value": get_table_filters() } );
    }
});
    var tableFilterArray = {};
}

function get_table_filters() {
    return JSON.stringify(tableFilterArray);
}
```